# How to match Gif background color with Scaffold's color?

Tags: flutter, animation, splash-screen, background-color, animated-gif

I am building an app so for the start I want splash screen to show up. I achieved this result by AnimatedSplashScreen package which is quiet convenient to work with. My splash screen is located another file, when I use my splash screen the gif background color is not matching my scaffold's color. Here you can see exactly what is happening:

[SplashScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnJUe.jpg)

I tried to change scaffolds background color it did not work out. Also I changed my Container background color, same as before. First I put my gif as a child to my Container like this:

```
        Container(
                height: 500,
                width: 500,
                 child: Image.asset(
                   "assets/images/logo_gif.gif",
                 ),
              ),
```

Then I used decoration to put my gif:

```
        Container(
                height: 500,
                width: 500,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo_gif.gif"),
                    //colorFilter: ColorFilter.linearToSrgbGamma(),
                  ),
                ),
               ),
```

Here in the second code I used colorFilter and this solved part of my problem, that some part of gif's background color matched with my Scaffold's color.
But again I don't have any clue why this is happening. If anyone knows what could be potentially causing to this problem, I would be appreciated your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your `gif` has a white background.

You just have to add a `backgroundColor: Colors.white` property to your `Scaffold` widget.

This will match your Gif background color with Scaffold's color.

Comment: Part of the gif's background color changed only.

Comment: share the image again

Comment: Here it is: https://postimg.cc/p93dwTfY

Comment: Can you get the gif background color

Comment: If you can then set the scaffold background color to it or you have to change the gif background color to white

Comment: In this case I can't see my gif itself. The only thing I see is just blank screen.